# sorting doesn't work for the following method

Tags: java, spring

I have the following `getTrans` method defined in my controller java file. Since it's for GET request, I can see the results(using SOAP UI client) for the 
following API call `http://localhost:8080/itl/fin/trans?bId=ABC2`   for the `bId = ABC2`.

I am trying to test the `sortBy` thing which isn't working properly and for that I am trying to test the URL like the following :

`http://localhost:8080/itl/fin/trans?bId=ABC2&sortBy=DESC`

**My Questions:**

1) Please let me know if above api call looks correct? Because when I ran the above URI on SOAP UI, I didn't see any change in the 
   JSON response as compared with the URI I tested in the first place.

2) Since sorting isn't working, is there anything wrong in the code below for sorting?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/itl/fin/trans", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<SetRESTData<FinTransactionDTO>> getTrans(

    @RequestParam(value = "bId", required = true) final String bId,
    @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) final String statusString,
    @RequestParam(value = "transactionMethod", required = false) final String transMethodString,
    @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false) final String orderBy,
    @RequestParam(value = "sortDirection", required = false) final String sortDirectionString) {

    final FinTransStatus status = StringUtils.isBlank(statusString) ? null : FinTransStatus.fromCode(statusString);
    final FinTransMethod method =
      StringUtils.isBlank(transMethodString) ? null : FinTransMethod.fromCode(transMethodString);

    final FinTransPaginationData paginationData = StringUtils.isBlank(orderBy) ?
      null : new FinTransPaginationData(FinTransSortableField.fromCode(orderBy), null, null, sortDirectionString);

    final ServiceResultDetails<Set<FinTransDTO>> resultsDetails =
      finTransService.getTransactionsForEmployeeUse(bId,status, method, paginationData);

    final ResponseCode errorCode = resultsDetails.getErrorCode();
    if (errorCode != null) {
      return buildNoCacheNoCorsEmptySetRESTDataWithMessage(errorCode, resultsDetails.getErrorMessage());
    } else {
      return buildNoCacheSetRESTDataResponse(
        resultsDetails.getEntity(), ResponseCode.FIN_TRANS_RETRIEVED, ResponseCode.FIN_TRANS_NOT_FOUND, false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can we see the code for `getTransactionsForEmployeeUse`, `FinTransPaginationData`, `FinTransMethod` and `FinTransStatus`. Also `buildNoCacheSetRESTDataResponse`

Comment: `SetRESTData` suggests a `Set` is used and that might be the issue (unless it's a `SortedSet`)

Answer (score 0):

I notice this in your code :

```
final FinTransPaginationData paginationData = StringUtils.isBlank(orderBy) ?
    null :
    new FinTransPaginationData(FinTransSortableField.fromCode(orderBy), null, null, sortDirectionString);
```

Maybe if `sortDirectionString` is empty, no sorting happens.. Only you knows since we don't have any code.

Comment: I am not specifying any value for `sortDirectionString` in the API call as shown above. Did you mean to say the same thing?

Comment: Yes, either test with a direction or check your code for what happens if `sortDirectionString` is empty or null.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate what should I specify for `sortDirectionString` in the following URI :`http://localhost:8080/itl/fin/trans?bId=ABC2&sortBy=DESC&sortDirectionString =      ` . I didn't understand when you mentioned `either test with a direction`.

Comment: You can try with ASC or DESC I guess.. But I don't know how your methods work.

Answer (score 0):

just a Controller method ,we can not sure whether is right or not,

```
 final FinTransPaginationData paginationData = StringUtils.isBlank(orderBy) ?
      null : new FinTransPaginationData(FinTransSortableField.fromCode(orderBy), null, null, sortDirectionString);
```

we don't know this line is right or not, may be your sort method is wrong?

you need to set a breakpoint and step by step, watching variable value whether your expected?